# woocommerce gallery image as temporary featured imageI

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to find a way to set a gallery image as the featured image, but just temporary. So basically what I'm trying to do is All my featured images are in front of white. After clicking a button, I want the products to use for example the 3rd gallery image, which is in front of a colored background, to show in my shop overview.

Any hint on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you already have code? You should paste it as an edit to your question!

Comment: No, as I don`t really know where to start.